# Prestashop 1.6.1.14 - Database Query Returns 1 on Execute

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am currently using the code below in Prestashop to retrieve a cart id.

```
    public function hookDisplayPDFInvoice($params) {

    $order_invoice = $params['object'];
    $id_order = (int)$order_invoice->id_order;

    $sql = 'SELECT id_cart FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders WHERE id_order="'.$id_order.'"';
    //example id_cart
    $id_cart = Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
    return $id_cart;
```

In database, there are id_cart and id_timeslot. Table is called ps_cart_timeslot.

I am quite stuck as I am baffled as to why the data return is 1 for any data I am retrieving.

$id_order is fine, it is returning the right value. Any data select I am querying will return 1.

Am I missing anything? Pardon me if this is a silly mistake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selects use `Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);` or to get single value use `Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);`

However since PS 1.6 you should be using query builder.

```
$query = new DbQuery();
$query->select('id_cart')
      ->from('orders')
      ->where('id_order = ' . (int)$id_order);
Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($query);
// Or array of values
Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($query);
```

`execute()` method returns only [true or false](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/db/Db.php#L606) while `executeS()` will return an array of select results (method can only be used for select queries) and `getValue()` will return the first value found in result.

Comment: You, my friend is a saviour. Is it a standard that I need to use in Prestashop 1.6? If so, can I just check is my queries wrong that it returned the wrong data?

Comment: @MuhammadFakhrinBinUmar It's not wrong but `execute()` method returns only true/false if query was successful, while `executeS()` will return select results as array and `getValue()` will return you the first value in the result.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.... precisely why I am having the returned data as it is. Thanks once again!